# Minimum distance between sum of powers of two

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Definition:** Define the weight, $w$, of a positive integer to be the number of 1s in its binary representation. So, $w(6)=2$ because $6_{10} = 110_2$.

**Problem:** Given a positive integer $n$, where $n \neq 2^k - 1$, find an integer $m$ such that $w(n) = w(m)$ and $|n - m|$ is minimized and $n \neq m$.

**My thoughts:**

I realized that the restriction of $w(n) = w(m)$ implies that we can think of the problem as swapping bits in $n$ to find the number $m$ that minimizes $|n - m|$.

My idea was that we would need to perform exactly one swap, because performing more swaps would increase the absolute difference. I have formalized a stronger version of my idea, but have been unable to make any progress and I am not even sure if it is true.

**Claim:**

$\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, \forall i_1, ..., i_k, j_1, ..., j_k \in 
\mathbb{N}$ where $i_s \neq i_t$ and $j_s \neq j_t$ when $s \neq t$

$\exists p \in \{1, ..., k\}$ such that $|2^{i_p} - 2^{j_p}| \leq |\sum_{r=1}^{r=k}2^{i_r}-2^{j_r}|$

**Question:** So, my question is: do you have any hints or even a proof/disproof of my claim? I am *not* asking for a solution to the problem stated above.

Comment: Which is the solution in the cases of the binary numbers $1011111\dots 1$ and $1000000\dots0$ and $1000000\dots01000000\dots0$?! (Is the situation dramatically changed if we add some significant digits in the above cases?!)

Comment: For 10111...1, the solution would be 11011...1.

For 10000...0, the solution would be 01000..0.

For 10000...01000...0, the solution would be 10000...0010...0.

I'm not sure how this helps with the claim I've posted. I also don't understand what you mean by adding significant digits.

Comment: Just an update, I was able to solve the posed problem, but still have been unable to make any progress on the claim.

Comment: I thought that the initial problem was the main issue, but ok, let us focus on the claim. For me it is hard to digest such predicates, some of them are declared, some of them ($s,t$) not. So i try to restate in words, hoping to get a clear claim. (For me the claimed proposition with many $\forall$ and $\exists$ in not clear at an important point, since the multiindices  $i=(i_1, \dots,i_k)$ and $j=\dots$ are **not sorted** in any manner.) So the Claim is: *Let $M,N$ be two numbers written in binary form, so that they have exactly $k$ one digits. Let $i$, $j$ be the multiindices of the...

Comment: ... places of the ones in $M$, respectively $N$, ordered increasingly. For instance, for $ M=100000101$ the places are $0$ (for the "last" $1$) $2$ for the mid one, and $8$ for the "significant" (or "first") one. So $i= (0,2,8)$. Assume $j=(1,3,4)$, so $N=11010$. Now the claim is that at least one of the differences (written with binary numbers) $01-10$, $100-1000$, $100000000-10000$, taken in absolute value, is smaller than $|M-N|$? (The difference is the sorting of the multiindices $i,j$.) If so, please adjust the claim...

Comment: Yes, that is a correct interpretation what I meant to say!

Comment: I've added an answer but apologies in advance if I have misunderstood your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $i$ denote the position of the 'place' signifying $2^i$. Then the transformation from $n$ to $m$ can be represented by a sequence of transpositions $$(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)...(a_kb_k), \text{ where } a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<...<a_k<b_k,$$
where $(a_ib_i)$ signifies that $N$ and $M$ have interchanged digits in the $a_i$th and $b_i$th places.

Let $M'$ and $N'$ be the numbers formed by ignoring the $b_1$ least significant bits of $M$ and $N$ respectively.

If $k>1$, then $|M'-N'|\ge1.$ Then $|M-N|\ge 2^{b_1+1}-(2^{b_1}-2^{a_1})=2^{b_1}+2^{a_1}$. Therefore $|M-N|$ is greater than or equal to $2^{b_1}-2^{a_1}$ with equality if and only if $k=1$ i.e. when there is just one swap.

Comment: I don't get it. Why is it that $|M-N|$ is greater than or equal to $2^{b_i}-2^{a_i}$ ?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to explain why.

Comment: Why $ a_1 < b_1 < a_2 < b_2 < ...$? Why can we not have $a_1 > b_1$, if for example $N=0010$ and $M=0001$? There, $a_1 = 2, b_1=1$.

Comment: The transposition (12) is identical to the transposition (21) so we can write them in the form given in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. If I understand correctly, you've constructed a lower bound for $|M-N|$ and shown that it only equals it when there is exactly one swap.

Comment: Glad to be of help